# Deploying Android App To Multiple Test Devices

Tags: android

I exported an unsigned apk file that represents a test version of my Android application.  I need to distribute this to quite a few users.  Is there a simple method to distribute the apk file where it will install the app?  I'm trying to avoid the test users from having to download something like Astro or the sdk. Any ideas?  I tried putting it out on a global web server and the file downloads but doesn't install.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you tell your testers to check the "Unknown sources" checkbox in the system's "Manage Application" settings?

Comment: If you host your apk file on the web some where, your users should be able to download it then select the downloaded file out of their notification bar and it should start the package installer for your apk

Comment: I'm pretty sure they won't be able to install an unsigned apk on their devices. It would simply say that the installation failed. You will have to sign it with a test key generated on your computer.

Comment: yeah the installation failed, I'll try to sign it.

Comment: @Jeshurun - add you comment as an answer as that is what fixed my install.  I had to install apk installer as well.

Comment: Sure, I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> The Android system will not install or run an application that is not
>   signed appropriately. This applies wherever the Android system is run,
>   whether on an actual device or on the emulator. For this reason, you
>   must set up signing for your application before you can run it or
>   debug it on an emulator or device.

So even if your users have the "Allow installing non-market apps" checked, your application will still have to be signed with at least a test key before it can be installed on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

I just put my experimental apps on the Android market with a description that says "don't install this, it won't work for you" and then give an access key to my testers.